# SQL - AND condition in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm setting up a new Photo Gallery web application and now I have some issue with a SQL query.

ERD:

I have a table `Photo` and a table `PeopleTag`. The relationship between these tables is n:n and so I created a third table `Photo_PeopleTag` for the foreign keys.

Columns:

- Photo --> Id, Filename etc
- PeopleTag --> Id, Name
- Photo_PeopleTag --> Id, PhotoId, PeopleTagId

Data from the `Photo_PeopleTag` table:

```
+----------------------------+
| ID | PhotoId | PeopleTagId |
+----------------------------+
| 1  |    1    |       2     |
| 2  |    2    |       2     |
| 3  |    2    |       8     |
| 4  |    4    |       3     |
+----------------------------+
```

Now I need a query which gives me only the picture(s), which the Peoples 2 AND 8 are tagged. In this case, that would be the PhotoId 2.

In this example there were only 2 people. But there will be other pictures with more as 2 peoples.

Does anyone have any idea what this query might look like?

The following code snippet didn't work --> 0 results

```
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Photo_PeopleTag] 
WHERE [PeopleTagId]  = '2' 
  AND [PeopleTagId]  = '8'
```

With this code snippet it would work, but there I have to set always a count value. And I'm not sure if this is really the correct way/code.

```
SELECT PhotoId 
FROM [dbo].[Photo_PeopleTag]
WHERE PeopleTagId IN ('2', '8')
GROUP BY PhotoId
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: this is correct way

Comment: _ERD:_ Um - where is the ERD?  And how did you define primary and foreign key constraints. No one should have to guess. And you should have a unique constraint on (PeopleTagId, PhotoId) for the junction table - do you?

Comment: @SMor,  I didn't upload the ERD because I thought it's not necessary. I used Linq to SQL to define they primary and foreign keys. Yes I have the unique constraint on this tables. Kind Regards Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current query is close, but you need to assert the *distinct* count of people tags:

```
SELECT PhotoId
FROM [dbo].[Photo_PeopleTag]
WHERE PeopleTagId IN (2, 8)
GROUP BY PhotoId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT PeopleTagId) = 2;
```

For the particular case where you are checking for only two tags, I prefer to write the above as:

```
SELECT PhotoId
FROM [dbo].[Photo_PeopleTag]
WHERE PeopleTagId IN (2, 8)
GROUP BY PhotoId
HAVING MIN(PeopleTagId) <> MAX(PeopleTagId);
```

This version leaves open the possibility of the database using an index on the `PeopleTagId` column to speed up the query (though perhaps not on SQL Server).  When asserting three or more tags, we can't use this trick though.

Answer (score 1):

In your query

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Photo_PeopleTag] where [PeopleTagId]  = '2' AND [PeopleTagId]  = '8'
```

The "AND" doesn't search for records with PeopleTagId = 2 and also for (other) records with PeopleTagId = 8.

Rather it tries to search for records where both conditions apply: the PeopleTagId in each record found is 2 and also 8. Which of course can never happen, so you get 0 results.

You want an "OR" here, you want records where that PeopleTagId is either 2 or 8. As an alternative you can also use `PeopleTagId in (2, 8)`.

The full `WHERE` condition must apply to any record that is returned.

Comment: Hey Hans Keﬆing, thank you for your explination. Unfortunately I really need the AND and not the OR operator. The aim of the query should be to obtain all images containing at least both persons (2 AND 8). Kind Regards Marc

Answer (score 0):

The issue is if you use 'AND' then the query will execute only if both the conditions are TRUE. Instead you should try and use the OR operator. I have written a code for you, try it and let me know.

```
SELECT Photo.Id, Photo.Filename,  
PeopleTag.Id, PeopleTag.Name
FROM [Photo_PeopleTag]
join Photo on Photo.Photo_ID=Photo_PeopleTag.Photo_ID
join PeopleTag on PeopleTag.PeopleTag_ID=Photo_PeopleTag.PeopleTag_ID
where PeopleTag.Id=2 or PeopleTag.Id=8
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey Tejaswini Nanaware, thank you for your code snippet. Unfortunately I really need the AND and not the OR operator. The aim of the query should be to obtain all images containing at least both persons (2 AND 8). Kind Regards Marc

Comment: You're welcome Ma Bu :) Glad you found the solution! :D

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will give you the photo file name with the people 2 and 8 both are tagged

```
Select P.Filename
from Photo P
inner join Photo_PeopleTag PPT
on PPT.PhotoId = P.Id
where PPT.PeopleTagId = 2 and PPT.PeopleTagId  = 8
```

Comment: Hey Anand Nikhil Bharti, thank you very much for your Code snippet. Unfortunately I got no result if I used your query. Kind Regards Marc